# Replacing spaces by 0's in an array (Python)

Tags: python, spaces, zero

Evening/Morning

I've been for the past two days trying to make a program that does a hill cipher. I only have only problem so far and it is that I can't find a way to replace the spaces to 0's. I have tried doing different conditions wich might (or in my case don't) work, I either get nothing shown on screen or the ascii value from space -96. This is what I got so far:

```
import math
import sys
import string
import numpy as np
from numpy import matrix

msg = sys.argv[1]
key1 = sys.argv[2]
key2 = sys.argv[3]
key3 = sus.argv[4]
key4 = sys.argv[5]
base = sys.argv[6]

key_matrix = np.matrix([[int(key1), int(key3)], [int(key2), int(key4)]])
lettconv = [ord(lett) - 96 for lett in msg]
```

code might be a little nasty, sorry about that, I'm still a noob with python and programming in general.
Anything would be great, I would rather have an explanation on how to do it since it is stuff to do for my uni, I'm pretty lost and could use some guidance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I am understanding this correctly, in the list comprehension you want to use the value `0` if the letter is a space, otherwise you want to use `ord(lett) - 96`.  You can use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to express this logic as follows:

```
0 if lett == ' ' else ord(lett) - 96
```

Putting this into the comprehension:

```
lettconv = [0 if lett == ' ' else ord(lett) - 96 for lett in msg]
```

Comment: Oh man, I never even thought about that, was trying to do the if condition outsite of the lettconv array I was doing, no wonder it never showed anything. Thanks a lot! it works now :)